# How to get partner's booking reference on BA Avios reservation?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, british-airways, alaska-airlines

I booked an Alaska ticket using BA Avios. BA gives their own booking reference which Alaska doesn't recognize. How to find the Alaska booking reference for this reservation? It doesn't seem to be immediately available on ba.com.

Comment: Have you tried checkmytrip by any chance? Not sure whether that works for non-Amadeus bookings, but it may be worth a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately that's  a common problem with codeshare itineraries. A few suggestions

1. Check your confirmation email or invoice (receipt). Sometimes it's in there, even if it's not on the website.
2. Call Alaska. They should be able to find the reservation through either the BA PNR (Passenger Name Record = booking reference) or by name and flight info. If they have it, they should be able to give you their own PNR. If they can't find it you have a bigger problem and need to go to step 3.
3. Call BA. If Alaska can't find your reservation, they need to confirm that it actually exists and need to give you enough information so that Alaska can find it.

Comment: In some cases you need the ticket number rather than the (BA) booking reference when asking them to locate your file.

Comment: Sigh.... #2 worked (with the BA ticket number). Alaska has a very useful chat feature on their website, so I didn't actually have to talk to any human.